# How to redirect permanently (301) via .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

Hey guys! Can you please advise me how to modify my .htaccess so that

```
http://example.com (non-www without trailing slash)
http://example.com/ (non-www with trailing slash)
http://www.example.com (www without trailing slash)
```

will be permanently redirected (301) to

`http://www.example.com/ (www with trailing slash)`?

Additionally, are there general rules to apply this "behavior" to **subfolders**

```
http://example.com/subfolder
http://example.com/subfolder/
http://www.example.com/subfolder
=> http://www.example.com/subfolder/
```

and **subdomains** (reversely here)

```
http://www.subdomain.example.com
http://www.subdomain.example.com/
http://subdomain.example.com
=> http://subdomain.example.com/
```

as well? As I'm completely new to this, please be kind... =)

Thanks! Nel

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Thanks Ignacio! I've already given the doc a try but must admit that most of it simply goes over my head... =) I'm looking for an "one-fits-it-all" solution which makes it even harder... really need YOU, pros!

Comment: Nevermind, I misunderstood your question. You don't want a redirect, you want to rewrite as the other answers discussed. Deleted my misguided answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These three rules should do all the things you want:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite www.subdomain.example.com to subdomain.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)\.example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://%1.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# Rewrite example.com to www.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# Add trailing slash to all URIs without one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hey You! =) I think that is what I'm looking for - thanks a bunch! Will I have to add "RewriteEngine On" and "RewriteBase /" here as Eric quoted?

Comment: Only RewriteEngine On, i believe. (I'll edit my answer as well)

Answer (score 2):

The DirectorySlashes directive takes care of the trailing slash problem.

The non-www to www redirect is:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.example\.com)?$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do the trick:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]
```